# Can I create awk variables from current lines?

Tags: variables, awk

I have two lines:

```
Pid: 2
PPid: 1
```

And I need to print something like this:

```
PID_Process=2:PPID_Process=1
```

I have this but it doesn't quite work:

```
awk -v PID='NR==1{$2}' 
    -v PPID='NR==2{$2}'
    '{print "PID="PID, "PPID="PPID}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-v` creates variables before awk begins. To assign them while it's running you want something like this:

```
awk 'NR==1 {PID=$2}
     NR==2 {PPID=$2}
     END {print "PID="PID, "PPID="PPID}'
```

Or simpler:

```
awk 'NR==1 {PID=$2}
     NR==2 {PPID=$2; print "PID="PID, "PPID="PPID; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F': *' '
    { printf "%s%s_Process=%s", sep, toupper($1), $2; sep=":" }
    END { print "" }
' file
PID_Process=2:PPID_Process=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other variation

```
awk 'NR==1 {f=$2;next} {print "PID_Process="f":PPID_Process="$2}' file
PID_Process=2:PPID_Process=1
```